# Derivative of vector-tensor-vector product wrt tensor

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, tensors, classical-mechanics

In the context of continuum mechanics I need to compute the derivative

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial C}\left( \vec{e}_1\cdot\bar C \vec{e}_1\right)$$

with $\vec{e}_1$ the first cartesian unit vector, $C$ a symmetric rank 2 tensor and $\bar C = J^{-\frac{2}{3}} C$, $J = \det(C)^\frac{1}{2}$.

Question: Is the following statement true? $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial C} \left(\vec{e}_1\cdot\bar C \vec{e}_1\right) = \vec{e}_1\cdot\frac{\partial\bar C}{\partial C} \vec{e}_1 $$

Attempt to prove:

- text book results:
  $$ \frac{\partial\bar C}{\partial C} = J^{-\frac{2}{3}}(\mathbb{I} - \frac{1}{3} C\otimes C^{-1}) $$
  ($\mathbb{I}$: rank 4 identity)
  $$ \frac{\partial J^{-\frac{2}{3}}}{\partial C} = -\frac{1}{3}J^{-\frac{2}{3}} C^{-1} $$
- 1. alternative:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial C} \left(\vec{e}_1\cdot\bar C \vec{e}_1\right) = \frac{\partial J^{-\frac{2}{3}}C_{11}}{\partial C} = -\frac{1}{3}C_{11}J^{- \frac{2}{3}} C^{-1}  + J^{-\frac{2}{3}}\frac{\partial C_{11}}{\partial C} $$
where the last derivative is $\frac{\partial C_{11}}{\partial C_{ij}}\vec e_i\otimes\vec e_j = \vec e_1\otimes\vec e_1$, hence

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial C} \left(\vec{e}_1\cdot\bar C \vec{e}_1\right) =J^{- \frac{2}{3}}(\vec e_1\otimes\vec e_1 -\frac{1}{3}C_{11} C^{-1}) $$

- 2. alternative:

$$ \vec{e}_1\cdot\frac{\partial\bar C}{\partial C} \vec{e}_1  = \vec e_1\cdot\left(J^{-\frac{2}{3}}(\mathbb{I} - \frac{1}{3} C\otimes C^{-1})\right)\vec e_1 = J^{- \frac{2}{3}}(\vec e_1\otimes\vec e_1 - \frac{1}{3}\vec e_1\cdot(C\otimes C^{-1})\vec e_1)
$$

The last expression can be written in tensor notation as
$$ C_{ij}C^{-1}_{pq}\vec e_1\cdot(\vec e_i \otimes\vec e_j\otimes\vec e_p\otimes\vec e_q)\vec e_1 = C_{ij}C^{-1}_{pq}\delta_{1i} (\vec e_j\otimes\vec e_p)\delta_{q1} = C_{1j}C^{-1}_{1p} \vec e_j\otimes\vec e_p $$

which differs from $C_{11}C^{-1}_{ij}$.

Maybe this proves that $ \frac{\partial}{\partial C}\left( \vec{e}_1\cdot\bar C \vec{e}_1\right) \neq \vec{e}_1\cdot\frac{\partial\bar C}{\partial C} \vec{e}_1 $ but I don't quite trust my analysis.
Thank you for any comments!

Comment: Just to check: the $\frac{\partial}{\partial C}$ surrounds the entire expression?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat Yes, edited to add parenthesis for clarity

Comment: When you look at an expression like $e_1 (C \otimes C^{-1} e_1$ you have to be very careful to keep track which "tensor slots" the two $e_1$s are going into. In your alternative 2 you are plugging one of the two into the wrong slot.

Comment: @WillieWong: thanks! How do I know that the correct "slots" are in fact $i$ and $j$?

Comment: By reading your "Textbook result" and thinking carefully about what is being written down? Alternatively I would highly suggest learning to love [abstract index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) which makes these kinds of questions moot.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer "bashing" such expressions. What I mean by that is to reduce everything to einstein summation convention, and then compute the derivative using regular calculus. I'm also going to call $\vec e_1$ as just $e$ for simplicity.

$$
J = \sqrt{det(C)} = \sqrt{ \epsilon_{ijk} C_{1i} C_{2j} C_{3k}} \\
\overline{C}_{ab} = (J^{2/3}C)_{ab} =  (\epsilon_{ijk} C_{1i} C_{2j} C_{3k})^{1/3}C_{ab} \\
(\overline Ce)_p = \overline C_{ap} {e}_p \\
$$

Now that we have all the expressions, we can compute the expression:

\begin{align*}
e \cdot   \overline C e &= e_p (\overline C e)_p \\
 &= e_p   (\overline C_{ap} {e}_p) \\ 
&= \overline C_{ap} e_p^2 \\ 
&=  [(\epsilon_{ijk} C_{1i} C_{2j} C_{3k})^{1/3}C_{ap}] e_p^2
\end{align*}

from where we can mechanically now find the derivative $\frac{\partial(e \cdot   \overline C e)}{\partial C_{xy}}$ using the chain rule and that
 $\frac{\partial C_{ab}}{\partial C_{xy}}= \delta_{ab} \delta{xy}$

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand my mistake, together with Willie Wongs comment. I think you made some mistakes with the $p$ and $a$ indices though.